# Storing new mail from my mailbox into database

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, express, email

I want to store my new mails into postgresql database.

this is my main code, i was expecting it to show the new mail in console, but it won't

```
import {
    MailListener,
    IMailObject,
    IMailAttachment
} from "mail-listener-typescript";   


const options = {
    username: "xxx@gmail.com", // mail
    password: "xxx", // pass
    host: "imap.gmail.com", // host
    port: 993, // imap port
    tls: true, // tls
    connTimeout: 10000, // Default by node-imap
    authTimeout: 5000, // Default by node-imap,
    debug: console.log(), // Or your custom function with only one incoming argument. Default: null
    tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
    mailbox: "INBOX", // mailbox to monitor
    searchFilter: ["NEW"], // the search filter being used after an IDLE notification has been retrieved
    },
};

const MailListenerTS = new MailListener(options);

MailListenerTS.start();

MailListenerTS.on("mail", async function (mail: IMailObject, seqno: any, attributes: any) {
    if (mail.attachments.length > 0) {
    var mailAttachments: IMailAttachment[] = []

    for (let attachment of mail.attachments) {
        mailAttachments.push(attachment)
    }
    let mailData ={
        name: mail.from.value[0].name,
        sender: mail.from.value[0].address,
        date: new Date(mail.date),
        files: mailAttachments
    }
    
    console.log(mailData)
    }
});
```

and my tables are:
context: id, subject, message
user: id, email

Comment: You're only logging to the console for mail that has attachments though. And what does postgresql have to do with any of this?

Comment: Try adding an error event listener see if there's anything being logged there.